# Decision Tree Regression and Splits

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cart

I get that a decision tree regressor aims to find a function of the form

$$y = f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{M}c_m \mathbb{I}\{ x \in R_m\}$$

I have googled this online but I cant find a good enough answer.

I cant see how the algorithm decides how to find the regions $R_m$ to end the iterations with. One way could be to uniformly slice up the space of $y$ values. But this graph suggests that more to it than this.

[image]

Comment: In other words, are you interested in knowing how decision tree decides on the splits points at each leaft?

Comment: Yes I guess so.